# Rails ActiveRecord searching JSON with mixed case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When I do a query such as...

`Notification.where("jobData @> 'to => 07517058658'")`

[Or any variant of this, for searching JSON]

I get the following error back

`column "jobdata" does not exist`

It seems to be impossible to include the capital D in the query.

Comment: Did you try `"'jobData' @> ..."`?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousFunction: ERROR:  operator is not unique: unknown @> unknown`